# How do I delete a non-existing document from elasticsearch in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-model

In a model class, I have the following code to delete an indexed document in ElasticSearch (as per the [documentation](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/elasticsearch-model/)):

```
after_commit on: [:destroy] do
  __elasticsearch__.delete_document rescue nil
end
```

I am using `rescue nil` to catch the 404 exception ElasticSearch raises when it can't find the document.

The problem is that the exception still bubbles up, the `rescue nil` code doesn't catch it.

How do I delete a document in ElasticSearch regardless of whether it exists or  not?

Answer (score 5):

You can use the [`:ignore` parameter](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/elasticsearch-api/Elasticsearch/API/Actions:delete) in the `delete_document` call in order to ignore 404 errors.

```
after_commit on: [:destroy] do
  __elasticsearch__.delete_document ignore: 404
end
```

Answer (score 2):

This code works ok:

```
after_commit on: [:destroy] do
  __elasticsearch__.client.delete index: Dataset.index_name, type: Dataset.document_type, id: id, ignore: 404
end
```